# Can gcc prefetch through two arrays? (indirect prefetch)

Tags: caching, gcc, optimization, prefetch

Suppose I have two arrays `a` and `b` that are initially not in cache. I have a loop incrementing `i` computing some function of `b[a[i]]`. Will gcc be able to insert the necessary prefetch so that `b[a[i]]` will be in cache once we get deep in the loop?

Answer (score 3):

No gcc doesn't do it (at least for modern x86-64-architectures). For example, compiled with `-O2`, the following simple code:

```
double calc(int *add, double *ptr, int N){
    double res=0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
       res+=1.0/ptr[add[i]];
    return res;
}
```

results in the assembler without prefetch, here is only the loop, [the whole code on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/XPCTWC):

```
...
.L3:
        movslq  (%rdi), %rax
        movapd  %xmm2, %xmm1
        addq    $4, %rdi
        cmpq    %rdi, %rdx
        divsd   (%rsi,%rax,8), %xmm1
        addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        jne     .L3
        rep ret
...
```

But then, gcc doesn't usually do any prefetching also for direct accesses:

```
double calc(double *ptr, int N){
    double res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
       res+=1.0/ptr[i];
    return res;
}
```

with resulting loop ([the whole assembler here](https://godbolt.org/g/6axqGG)):

```
...
.L3:
        movapd  %xmm2, %xmm1
        addq    $8, %rdi
        divsd   -8(%rdi), %xmm1
        cmpq    %rax, %rdi
        addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        jne     .L3
        rep ret
...
```

Usually, gcc doesn't mess with caching/prefetching and leaves it to the hardware.

As your rightly pointed out, `-fprefetch-loop-arrays` would prompt gcc to prefetch the data ([whole assembler](https://godbolt.org/g/ofhsQT)):

```
.L4:
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
    addl    $8, %edx
    prefetcht0      (%rax)   ;!!! HERE PREFETCH FOR FUTURE
    addq    $64, %rax
    divsd   -160(%rax), %xmm2
    addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
    divsd   -152(%rax), %xmm2
    addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
    divsd   -144(%rax), %xmm0
    addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
    divsd   -136(%rax), %xmm0
    addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
    divsd   -128(%rax), %xmm2
    addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
    divsd   -120(%rax), %xmm2
    addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
    divsd   -112(%rax), %xmm0
    addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
    divsd   -104(%rax), %xmm0
    cmpl    %ecx, %edx
    addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    jne     .L4
```

However, this doesn't make the program faster - the hardware is clever enough to prefetch the data on its own without hints from compiler. Not sure which feature is responsible for that, my guess would be the [out-of-order-execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution).

You have raised the issue, that there is not enough "work" to be interleaved with fetching of the data. That is true, but even for functions like

```
double calc(double *ptr, int N){
    double res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        res+=1.0/ptr[i]*ptr[i]/ptr[i]*ptr[i]/ptr[i]*ptr[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

[nothing changes](https://godbolt.org/g/rXBdRr).

One last question: What happens with `-fprefetch-loop-arrays` and indirect access as in the first example? We can easily [see](https://godbolt.org/g/ZP8zCN), that only the `add`-array is prefetched, but not the `ptr`-array:

```
.L4:
        movslq  -40(%rax), %r8
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
        prefetcht0      (%rax)  ;HERE rax CORRESPONDS TO add !!
        addl    $16, %ecx
        addq    $64, %rax
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm2
        movslq  -100(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm2
        movslq  -96(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm0
        movslq  -92(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm0
        movslq  -88(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm2
        movslq  -84(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm2
        movslq  -80(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm0
        movslq  -76(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm0
        movslq  -72(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm2
        movslq  -68(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm2
        movslq  -64(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm0
        movslq  -60(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm0
        movslq  -56(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm2
        movslq  -52(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm2
        movslq  -48(%rax), %r8
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm0
        movslq  -44(%rax), %r8
        cmpl    %r9d, %ecx
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm2
        movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
        divsd   (%rsi,%r8,8), %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
        jne     .L4
```

Comment: This is a very thorough answer, thank you. For some reason I thought gcc was much more aggressive with throwing in prefetch instructions!

Comment: However, I do worry that those examples are biased -- very little work is being done with the fetched memory, so prefetching can't help. If you did enough computation with each line of cache to give time to fetch a new line of cache the misses could have been completely avoided! I wonder if gcc would catch that case?

Comment: Also, I believe this flag may change the behavior: `-fprefetch-loop-arrays `. From https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/prefetch.html

Comment: You are right, but on the modern cpu inserting prefetches doesn't make program faster. Still it might be important for less clever /older architectures. See also my update for more details.